# Query S3 json file in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have json file uploaded to s3
then I wrote the following code to Query this file

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new aws.S3();
const bucket = 'hotels.mserver.online';
const objectKey = 'hotelsrates.json';

exports.handler = (event,context,callback) => {
    // TODO implement

    const response = getS3Objects(bucket,objectKey); //s3.listObjectsV2({}).promise();
    console.log(response);
};

function getS3Objects(bucket,key) {
    return s3.getObject({ Bucket:bucket, Key:key, ResponseContentType:'application/json '})
        .promise().then(file => { return file })
        .catch(error => { return error });
}`
```

but the result is getting null .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand what you are trying to accomplish here but that is not the right way to do it.

```
function getS3Objects(bucket,key){
    return s3.getObject({Bucket:bucket,Key:key,ResponseContentType:'application/json'})
               .promise().then(file=>{return file})
               .catch(error =>{return error});
}`
```

The part above will still return a promise object, which means that you need to handle it accordingly. Instead of `const response = getS3Objects(bucket,objectKey);` you want to do

```
getS3Objects(bucket,objectKey).then(response => console.log(response));
```

Inside of your `handler` function.

Furthermore, your usage of `s3.getObject` function is incorrect. Where first argument is an object - parameters, and the second argument is a callback function.

```
s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);
```

Therefore in your case, you want to modify your `getS3Objects` function a bit. If you want to use promises, then you can do it like this.

```
function getS3Objects(bucket, key) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        s3.getObject(
            {
                Bucket: bucket,
                Key: key,
                ResponseContentType: 'application/json'
            },
            (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your comment ,but still got null for response and I don't know why??

Comment: what if I wanna pass 2 filtration to get the result some thing like this inside the handler.

Comment: var params={"Bucket":bucket,"Key":key}
   s3.getObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
    console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else 
    {
        console.log(data);
       var json = JSON.parse(new Buffer(data.Body).toString("utf8"));
       SELECT * FROM json s WHERE s.hotelID =filter.ID and s.targetDay =filter.date
       // var json=JSON.stringify(data.Body);
        console.log(json);
        //console.log(json.find(filter));
    }
   
});
};

Answer (score 0):

Another way that you can do this is as follows:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

async function readFile(Bucket, Key) {
  const params = {
    Bucket,
    Key,
    ResponseContentType: 'application/json',
  };

  const f = await s3.getObject(params).promise();
  return f.Body.toString('utf-8');
}

readFile('mybucket', 'xyz.json').then(console.log);
```

Comment: Just to note that you can set up handler as async function as well, in which case you can use the `async/await` syntax when you are calling `readFile` as well.